# Positioning of UIBarButtonItem in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have an iPad app which, when in portrait, works fine. However, in landscape (even if forced to only use landscape), the UIBarButtonItems I add appear slightly too far to the right, such that they are partly disappearing off the right hand side of the screen.
Here is a snippet of the code I am using to create and add the buttons:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:iv];
    SDZFESServices *service = [SDZFESServices service];
    [service setServiceUrl:[app serviceUrl]];
    [service GetSeatingPlan:self action:@selector(SeatingPlanReturn:) group_id:[group ItemID] group_type:@"COU"];
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Seating plan: %@", [group ItemName]];
    UIBarButtonItem *bbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(SaveSeatingPlan:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:bbi];
```

}

Any ideas? Only the left hand half of the button will be visible.

Comment: Try adding the buttons in `viewWillAppear`.  The layout of the views (e.g., their size, orientation, ...) is not complete during `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but same issue :-/